# Function problem vs decision problem

Tags: complexity-theory, decision-problem, search-problem

I am a mathematician novice with the theory of computer science. During the course I took, we dealt with decisional problems (introducing D, SD, coSD classes language side, and P, NP, coNP, EXP, DP, AC0, complexity side) while we have only mentioned the function problems.

I used the book Automata, computability and complexity by Elain Rich, and I read superficially a book by Papadimitriou (I don't remember the title, sorry).

Since both books mention the FP and FNP classes, I would like to learn more about these topics: It seems to me that every function problem can be "transformed" in un decisional problem and vice-versa, however complexity is not conserved, right?

Could you suggest me a book about function problems and their complexity classes? Thank you.